# For any Linux Distro's packaging system, find the maximum number of simultaneously installable packages

Tags: linux, debian, package-managers, dpkg

Some packages *conflict*, so it's impossible to install all available packages at once.  What's the maximum possible number of installable packages for a given system?  A brute-force trial and error method would be:

1. make a list of every possible of package name, *i.e.* `dglob -a > list`
2. from that, make sublists `slist1 slist2 slist3 ...` of every possible package [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).  On my system `dglob -a | wc -l` returns *91327*, which would require an [unfeasibly large number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content)  (*1.467×10^27492*) of [files](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-worlds-total-data-storage-capacity).
3. run `apt-get install` on each list, and `rm` those that produce conflicts.
4. sort remaining lists by number of lines, and show the longest one.
   `wc -l slist* | head -n -1 | sort -g | tail -1`.

Easy, but too heavy on resources, so maybe there's some more feasible method.

Various related questions follow from that, such as:

- given a package *'foo'*, how to find the maximum number of installable packages that don't conflict with *'foo'*?
- For all possible packages, which has the smallest such maximum, (making it the most "quarrelsome" package)?

(*Note: The question applies to Debian, Red Hat, and any distro or OS with a packaging system that maps out package conflicts.  Answers for any applicable platform would be valid.*)

---

Background:

*Debian* has tens of thousands of packages.  `dglob` (from the *debian-goodies* package) is handy for getting a quick count:

```
# show how many packages installed and available on the current system
echo $(dglob    | wc -l) packages installed of \
     $(dglob -a | wc -l) packages.
```

Example output, (both numbers may periodically fluctuate after updates and upgrades, and will vary between systems):

```
5107 packages installed of 91327 packages.
```

The number *5107*'s not a maximum of course, but there must be a maximum.

Comment: Questions about general software are off-topic, since **every** package isn't *focused* on tools for software development. Your question might be a better fit for the [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site. However, how many **mp3 players** do you really need to install?

Comment: Oddly enough, for this question the _contents_ of the packages are wholly irrelevant.  Since it makes no difference, then if you like, let us suppose a Debian distro exists consisting _exclusively_ of that subset of Debian packages specifically intended for software development.  The question of how to feasibly find a maximum number of installable packages would be unchanged.    (Also, see the first line of the OP, which begins with "Note:...", where your question about mp3 players was anticipated, and in part answered.)

Comment: *The question of how to feasibly find a maximum number of installable packages would be unchanged* And still entirely general use.

Comment: Think of it as more of a graph theory and logical problem, which maps to a given package dataset, and whether or not the problem can be solved with the programming tools at hand.  It's not a strictly Debian puzzle, it could be asked of Red Hat *.rpm* files, or any distro's packaging system, or on any OS with a conflicting package tree, and any platform whatsoever.  Solve one in the abstract, solve them all.  Perhaps this question needs clarifying with regards to that...

Comment: as you rightly claim that this is a general problem of logic and graph-theory, you might want to ask the question on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) (or similar)

Comment: What about packages that don't conflict, but are superceeded by others? Kernels for example... you only need one, but there are lots available in apt...

Comment: @ivanivan, For the sake of the question assume that a superseded status is not relevant, and consider only whether packages conflict or do not conflict.  (In other words, yes, install a thousand kernels if possible.)

Comment: Considering only the conflicts, you have an instance of the NP-complete minimum vertex cover problem. You want to choose a minimum set of packages to *not* install, which includes at least one member of each conflicting pair. The problem would be much more interesting if you also consider `Depends` relationships: `A` conflicts with `B`, but 10 packages depend on `A` and `7` depend on B, but maybe eliminating those 10 packages solves some other conflicts too, while eliminating the 7 doesn't gain you much elsewhere...

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, Starting with a package list and only their respective individual `Depends`, we can construct a complete `Conflicts` list.  (OTOH starting with a package list and only a their respective individual `Conflicts`, inferring their `Depends` could be quite ambiguous.)  For this question, it seems like the `Depends` and `Conflicts` relationships are kind of the same thing.

Comment: That makes sense... construct the complete downstream dependency list for each package in a conflicting pair, and take the Cartesian product of those lists to form a bigger conflict list. Then you have a regular old minimum vertex cover problem. But the graph becomes much bigger so this may not be the most efficient method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Sixteen months ago [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358112/for-any-linux-distros-packaging-system-find-the-maximum-number-of-simultaneous#comment60725546_36358112) already attempted to close this Q. for the same reason, which has already been addressed in the comments.  (*i.e.* dependencies and package management are even more relevant to programmers than users.)  If you are aware of additional reasons for closing, please specify.

Comment: @agc: and they were quite right, this question is simply *not on topic for this site*. There is no programming problem here, nor would a software developer need to be able to know this information in order to develop software, a package management system is *not a tool in that sense*. If you want to discuss what is and is not a tool in that respect, please post a question on [Meta].

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks for the prompt reply.  While it's obvious you feel strongly about the relevance of this question to *SE*, your comment is unclear.  It seems difficult to imagine generating a minimum conflicting packages number for Debian *without* programming.  Re: "*There is no programming problem here, nor does would a software developer need to be able to know this information in order to develop software, it is not a tool in that sense.*": very sorry, the sense of that sentence is unclear -- the pronoun "*it*" refers to which noun?

Comment: I've corrected my comment to make it clearer. If you have a specific piece of code to discuss, then discuss *that*. Otherwise, if this is really a 'how do I code this up' question, then the *too broad* close reason applies too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks.  Re "*specific piece of code*":  the Q. does outline a reasonably specific piece of brute-force code, "*(i.e. if it's a Debian system make lists of every possible combination of package names, and run `apt-get install` on each list, then sort for the longest conflict free list)* -- if you insist, I could write actual code that does that, but it *should* be obvious that it'll virtually never finish, so the description alone seems sufficient.

Comment: You don't need to `apt-get install` anything, just analyze the dependency graph as outlined in previous comments. Stack Overflow specifically isn't for *"what if..."* questions; apart from idle curiosity, is there a reason a developer would need to solve this problem? If graph analysis to find the largest subgraphs without conflicts is a problem you want to solve, you can remove all the package management stuff from the question (or, more realistically, ask a better-scoped new question).

Comment: @tripleee, I'm not sure how to analyze the dependency graph here, hence the question.  Re *"...developer would need..."*: see [a prior comment on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354709/on-topic-package-management-questions#comment502136_354714) which seems like a better venue for that discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute force option is the only option in this case.  Here is [a paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00697463) that will describe why in depth but the issue is that package installation and dependency/conflict resolution is a NP-Complete problem.

A problem is in NP if every `TRUE` answer has an easily-checked polynomial-size explanation. In this case this can be done by listing the installed packages and available packages.

Debian package installation is in NP-hard if an efficient solution for the problem can be adapted to efficient solutions to every other problem in NP.  I will defer to the above listed paper as it is a bit complex to prove here but it can be encoded as [3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

As Debian package installation is in NP and NP-hard, thus it is NP-complete.

Here are some ways the `default` solver in APT tries to avoid the NP-completeness:

- Use of heuristics
- A preference for the first element in an or-group
- A strict package version convention
- Giving up when it encounters a major conflict.

Basically the constraints have to be specifically designed to get the problem to  fall into known tractable classes for a NP-Complete problem like [HORN-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability)

Unfortunately `find the maximum possible number of installable packages for a given system` pretty much excludes all of the known tractable classes that I am aware of.

So brute force is the *only* option and an expensive one until a suitable tractable class is discovered or if someone proves that P=NP.